# Android - Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: `getResources().getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary)`

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-support-design, android-appcompat, android-palette

I am following this tutorial [Flexibal Space with Image](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)

For design pattern for a toolbar called **Flexibal Space with Image** in android. While using `Palette` here I am stuck in following error in `java` file causing application to crash.

```
Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: `getResources().getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary)`
```

Follwing is my java file **YoutubeActivity.java**

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
int mutedColor = R.attr.colorPrimary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Praval Sharma");
    ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.header);
    Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary); //error 
            collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);      //error
        }
    });

}
}
```

And xml file **activity_youtube.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/newfloatnew"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

And **logcat**

```
04-21 17:27:16.660 14865-14865/com.praval.healthfreak W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
04-21 17:27:16.664 14865-14865/com.praval.healthfreak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.praval.healthfreak, PID: 14865
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.praval.healthfreak/com.praval.healthfreak.YoutubeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:197)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
at com.praval.healthfreak.YoutubeActivity.onCreate(YoutubeActivity.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

**( EDIT )** --- > app theme

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**(( Edit  ))** --> manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.praval.healthfreak">

<!-- To access internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- To access accounts configured on device -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- To use account credentials -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Splash">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Form">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".YoutubeActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".IndexPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_index_page"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".FoodEntry">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewIndex">

    </activity>
</application>
```

**EDIT**-->>  Removed action bar from activity but same error occurred as shown in logcat 
[image]

Comment: You need to add this to your theme:
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: Your Stacktrace actually contains a pretty readable error message: `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

Comment: @JonasKöritz what should I do to solve the problem

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad actually already provided you with the solution.

Comment: @JonasKöritz I know she gave good solution but it didn't work for me

Comment: Your error message should have changed, the Error stated above still suggests you did not make the changes.

Comment: I have made changes as you can see on screenshot added by me. I have removed action bar from activity.

Comment: dont remove actionbar from the activity.. just add the theme attribute mentioned in my answer to your <activity> tag in your manifest.. "AppTheme.NoActionBar".. Please update your code in the question after applying my changes if you still receive the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your theme

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YoutubeActivity" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you need add this "android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" inside you <activity> tag

Comment: Added but again app crashes. Actually problem is in java file in these lines `mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);` and `collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor); ` inside `onGenerated()` method.

Comment: when you comment this lines and remove the theme tag I mentioned above.. does the app work??
Since your stacktrace is identifying a completely different error..

Comment: I comment the lines but nothing happened. According to stacktrace `windowActionBar` should be `false` but it is already set as `false`

Comment: nothing happened means the app works in that case?
according to your manifest you arent using the theme that sets windowActionBar=false anywhere..
Also how are you so sure about the error coming from the Palette line? do you have any logs for the same? or is it a syntax error?

Comment: int  mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.md_deep_orange_700)); 
                collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);

Try this.. didnt receive any error at my end..

Comment: thanks error from java file has solved but error from action bar is not solved .

Answer (score 6):

**R.attr.colorPrimary** is the color ID.
Try it like this:

```
mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(getResources().getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary)); 
collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);
```

or for API 23+ use:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.attr.colorPrimary);
```

Comment: It is showing `getColor()` is deprecated and another error `Expected resource of type color` in `getColor()`

Comment: Just saw it's deprecated in Support Library 23. Try this: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);

Comment: Added but now how to modify `collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor); ` as same error is showing in this line also.

Comment: mutedColor should now be set to the actual color, instead of the resource ID. I don't know what else could be wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try R.color.colorPrimary instead of R.attr.colorPrimary. Specify colors in colors.xml file in res/values

Comment: Error remains after replacing `attr` to `color`. `Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: `getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)`

Comment: Also check that in colors.xml file you specify color as                          `<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>                         </resources>`

Answer (score 0):

Declare the int as ColorInt as follows

`@ColorInt
int mutedColor`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem, and here is my solution for this,

```
mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary);); 
collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);
```

Hope this helps!..

**Update:** I know it sounds funny/dumb, i just disabled the inspection, thats it no compile time error and no run time error. I just wanted to let you know guys.