# expected resource of type color for R.attr.colorPrimary

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, attr

I just want to set contentScrim programmatically. So I tried

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.attr.colorPrimary);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(color);
```

Then I tried

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(
        getResources().getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary));
```

But I keep getting complaints about `R.attr.colorPrimary`. Any help with this?

Someone seems to have ask this question [Android - Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here: `getResources().getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769062/android-should-pass-resolved-color-instead-of-resource-id-here-getresources). But what I tried is exactly what they suggested I should try. I am targeting minSDK 16.

BTW I cannot use `R.color.colorPrimary` because I want the dynamically set theme not some hardcoded/default color.

Answer (score 6):

```
public int getColor(Context context, int colorResId) {

    //return ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorResId); // Doesn't seem to work for R.attr.colorPrimary

    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[] {colorResId});
    int color = typedArray.getColor(0, 0);
    typedArray.recycle();
    return color;

}
```

Usage:

`int actualPrimaryColor = getColor(context, R.attr.colorPrimary);`

Comment: Can you edit your answer to also include if API is less than v31?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
int color = typedValue.data;

collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(color);
```

What I found in collapsingToolbarLayout documention, setContentScrimColor get color and not resource id